# custom, static home page / landing page with Twenty Eleven theme?

Tags: homepage, theme-twenty-eleven

I have a custom styled static page that I'd like to set as a home/landing page for a site using the Twenty Eleven theme. 
I can't seem to find any information on implementing a custom (ie- I made it) home/landing page for this particular theme, is it possible? How do I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the terminology is different but here are a few links to look at

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Basically
- save your custom page as custom-page-template.php in your theme folder
- create a new page from WordPress Menu
- choose your custom-page from the template drop down on the `add new page` page
- Save and View your page

Comment: possibly in connection with a page template http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Comment: details see pastebin http://pastebin.com/ZiteZrUX